# How to create a Playlist in JW Player using my YouTube Channel videos?

Tags: youtube-api, jwplayer, playlist, youtube-channels

I have a list of videos in my ***YouTube Channel***, from that list of videos I want to create a playlist in ***JW player***.

**Two things need to know :**

- How to get the videos from my YouTube channel
- How to create a playlist in JW player using that crawled videos
  (whether i can give    my YouTube link directly into `playlist`
  parameter of JW player or i    have to give as a separate video files
  in JW player parameters)

If anyone having experience in this API please guide me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to be __specific programming problems__ expressed _clearly_. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: I think now the question is clear ? If this one also could not readable or understandable, please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace your link to playlist:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
playlist:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL6cRJT5YYqLkZi7JU1e5LjsnBqJqPEh6m?alt=rss',
});
```

replace `PL6cRJT5YYqLkZi7JU1e5LjsnBqJqPEh6m` with your link to playlist

**EDIT**

to get channel video use

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERID/uploads?alt=rss
```

Comment: is it applicable for youtube channel or only for playlist ?

Comment: I added channel to my answer

Comment: Can you give detailed configuration in example

Comment: Because, i'm getting following error : "Error loading player:
No playable sources found"

Comment: Thank you Ben :) I have implemented successfully :)

Comment: great, do you still need full configuration example?

Comment: It's k Ben, I have integrated that.